# Stash variable in channel entries tag not working

Tags: stash

I’m having trouble getting a stash variable to work as a parameter in a channel entries loop. I have not had this problem before so I wonder if it may have something to do with the nature of the variable. It is coming from javascript code and it is called by the code . This produces the result of a city selected elsewhere on the page  (for example, Portland). Since that code can’t be  used in the channel entries tag I am using the following stash code:

```
{exp:stash:set
    name="city1"
    parse_tags="yes"
    process="end"
    trim="yes"}

    <label class="city"></label>

{/exp:stash:set}
```

This seems to work correctly and both {exp:stash:city1} and {exp:stash:get:blah name='city1’} produce the result of the selected city (for example, Portland). But it doesn’t work in the following expressionengine code:

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="place"
    search:city="{exp:stash:get:blah name='city1'}"
    parse="inward"
    dynamic="no"}

    {title}
    <br />

    {if no_results}
        No results
    {/if}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I’ve tried as many variants as I can think of using additional stash parameters but I need help.

Thanks,
Geoff

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the `parse="inward"` trick doesn't work with the `search:` parameters. You need to pass the variable as a placeholder to the channel entries tag instead. For example:

```
{exp:stash:parse unprefix="nested"}
   {exp:channel:entries
       channel="place"
       search:city="{stash:city1}"
       dynamic="no"}

       {title}
       <br />

       {if nested:no_results}
           No results
       {/if}

   {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:parse}
```